# LOGCAT : purging 197K from font cache

Tags: android, caching, fonts, logcat, purge

My android application logs such a messages, continuously.
Whta is it
I am not creating a typeface, just writing something with small font size on screen.

```
10-30 17:24:41.994: DEBUG/skia(26968): purging 197K from font cache [28 entries]
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, this is a Wild Guess(tm): You are setting the Typeface in an `onDraw()` method. Yes/no?

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue here. What's the problem with setTypeface? I'm using it in the c'tor of a custom TextView, in order to set a custom font on it. Tnx!